# How to access array based off of data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cloudkit

So I am creating an application with CloudkitJS, and I have a question on how to fetch user data. So users can create tasks, and the tasks are appended to a div on the page with data from that tasks object. On click of that tasks div it opens a popup of an html element that goes from display:none to display:inline-block, inside the popup is data from the appended div that was clicked (innerText, innerHTML, etc), but no actual data from the divs object in the array. Obviously just static html at that point. Each tasks info is stored in an object in an array. They are identified by record names. For simplicity, I made it A,B,C,D. That record is stored in the the object of the div's info. It is also stored in the div's data-record attribute. So the goal is that on click the document looks in the array for an object with a record of whatever the div that was clicked data-record is, and brings back everything from that object in an accesible variable. Any help, redirection or suggestions would be great. Thanks. If I can make it any more clear, let me know.

LINK - https://jsfiddle.net/1uh395cv/24/

```
var task1 = {
                "info": "nope",
                "recordName": "A",
                "dueDate": "dueDate"
            };
 var task2 = {
                "info": "nope",
                "recordName": "B",
                "dueDate": "dueDate"
            };
 var task3 = {
                "info": "nope",
                "recordName": "C",
                "dueDate": "dueDate"
            };
```

Comment: you should bind an attribute to the index of the array so that it knows which element it needs to retrieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `find` and `$.data`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var task1 = {    "info": "nope",    "recordName": "A",    "dueDate": "dueDate"  };  var task2 = {    "info": "nope",    "recordName": "B",    "dueDate": "dueDate"  };  var task3 = {    "info": "nope",    "recordName": "C",    "dueDate": "dueDate"  };

  var tasksss = [task1, task2, task3];
  $('div').click(function() {
    var record = $(this).data('record');
    var found = tasksss.find(function(t) {
      return t.recordName === record;
    });
    
    console.log(found);
  });
});
```

```css
[data-type="pinned"] {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed green;
  margin: 3px;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<div data-type="pinned" data-record="A">
data-record="A"
</div>
<div data-type="pinned" data-record="B">
data-record="B"
</div>
<div data-type="pinned" data-record="C">
data-record="C"
</div>
<div data-type="pinned" data-record="D">
data-record="D"
</div>
<div class="modal" style="display:none">
  This div is hidden.
</div>

</html>
```